# JS how to combinate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

How from array like this "myArray" I can get full combination of variants?

```
var myArray = [
    [1],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2]
];
```

I.e. I want array like this:

```
 var res = [
        [1,1,1],
        [1,1,2], 
        [1,2,1],
        [1,2,2],
        [1,3,1],
        [1,3,2]
    ];
```

Length of "myArray" can be different. Thanks for any help

```js
var myArray = [
  [1],
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2]
];

var length = myArray.length;
var rowsCount = 1;
myArray.map(function(item){
   rowsCount *= item.length;
});
  
var res = [],i,j;

for(i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++){
  // all needed rows 1...6
  for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
  // walk through arrays 0,1,2
      
        
   } 
    res.push([]); 
}

console.log(res.length);
```

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the [Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iterative approach can be completed as follows:

```js
function combinations(arr){
    const count = arr.reduce( (sum, a) => sum * a.length, 1 ),
        results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const acc = [];
        for (let j = arr.length, k = i; j--; k = Math.floor(k / arr[j].length)) {
            acc[j] = arr[j][k % arr[j].length];
        }
        results.push(acc);
    }
    return results;
}
// Sample data
var myArray = [
    [1],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2]
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(combinations(myArray)));
```

You can also use a recursive function for that. At each level of recursion you select a value from the corresponding subarray, adding it to a partial result. At the deepest level of recursion that will be a complete result that can be added to an array with all the results:

```js
function combinations(arr){
    var results = [];
    (function recurse(acc, i) {
        if (i >= arr.length) return results.push(acc);
        for (const val of arr[i]) {
            recurse(acc.concat(val), i+1);
        }
    })([], 0);
    return results;
}
// Sample data
var myArray = [
    [1],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2]
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(combinations(myArray)));
```